# Un-Cut my variable in R

Tags: database, r, variables, cut

here is my data

> hpy2

```
HappinessBW10.11.2000.08 LifeExpectancy.2004 Anger.2006.2009 Sadness.2011.2013
1                       6.35         (58.5,82.2]              16                 6
3                       4.63         (34.9,58.5]              16                16
4                       5.78         (58.5,82.2]              20                11
5                       5.20         (34.9,58.5]              16                10
6                       5.56         (58.5,82.2]              22                 8
7                       5.02         (58.5,82.2]              36                25
8                       4.92         (34.9,58.5]              16                19
9                       4.25         (34.9,58.5]              20                27
10                      4.58         (58.5,82.2]              11                21
12                      4.96         (34.9,58.5]              22                17
14                      4.28         (34.9,58.5]              10                 6
15                      6.19         (58.5,82.2]              18                33
16                      6.64         (58.5,82.2]              24                19
17                      5.06         (58.5,82.2]              25                22
18                      5.49         (58.5,82.2]              16                19
19                      5.90         (58.5,82.2]              15                20

>
```

By mistake, I used the cut function on my LifeExpectancy.2004

```
hpy2$LifeExpectancy.2004 <- cut(hpy2$LifeExpectancy.2004, 2)
```

variable, and as you can see, it gave me that nasty split of data. I want to know if there is a way to undo this?

Comment: Nope. The original values are gone, unless you have them stored somewhere else.

Comment: A many-to-one transformation isn't invertible.

Answer (score 0):

I would say its not possible because the intervals introduce ambiguity

Take the following example

```
> mtcars$cyl
 [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4

> cut( mtcars$cyl, 2)

 [1] (4,6] (4,6] (4,6] (4,6] (6,8] (4,6] (6,8] (4,6] (4,6] (4,6] (4,6] (6,8] (6,8] (6,8] (6,8]
[16] (6,8] (6,8] (4,6] (4,6] (4,6] (4,6] (6,8] (6,8] (6,8] (6,8] (4,6] (4,6] (4,6] (6,8] (4,6]
[31] (6,8] (4,6]
Levels: (4,6] (6,8]

> str(ycut)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "(4,6]","(6,8]": 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 ...
```

Let's look at the third element of mtcars$cyl[3] = 4, the third element of the cut is (4,6], all we know is that the original value in the numeric vector lands somewhere in that range, keeping in mind that the default behavior with include.lowest = FALSE is why we have the exclusive endpoint with 4, the lowest value of the vector. Take a second example mtcars$cyl[4] = 6. The 4th element of cut is also (4,6], which tells us again the 4th element from the numeric vector landed **somewhere** in that range. That 4th element could have been 5.5 and it would still be true. So in general cut is not invertible, but I would conjecture that it may be invertible for some specific choice of numeric vector and break count, but looking at your floating point data I'd say that's not the case for you.